# How to sort dataview according to input string?

Tags: c#, sorting, dataview

i Have a dataview with Employee Name. When i type "na" in the filtering box it comes up with this result. filtered and sorted ASC order.

```
Amina
Anna
Masud Rana
Nasima
```

But i want it sorted according to my input string "na". Expected result is something like this

```
Nasima
Anna
Amina
Masud Rana
```

thnx for any suggestion :)

Comment: are you aware of using the Sort Method..? `this.GridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["Column Name you want to sort on"],ListSortDirection.Ascending);`

Comment: yes i have use this sort. TransferEmployeeFilterView.Sort = "EmployeeName";  But this gives me result sorted in alphabetic method. Which gives me the first result i have mentioned here. But i would like to get the second result which will not sort a column just asc/desc rather depending on Input string ("na") in my filter box.

Comment: @AnupamRoy I think for this kind of sorting, you must use "Like" Wildcard in your query instead of DataView.May you plz show your "Search" query...

Comment: `TransferEmployeeFilterView.RowFilter = "EmployeeName LIKE '%" +txtSearchValue.Text.ToUpper() + "%'" ;                         
    TransferEmployeeFilterView.Sort = "EmployeeName"; `                  this is what i did to get filtered data according to the input string (say : "na") and sort it down. But i want the sorting depending on the input string not general alphabetic way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sorting with filter is not possible directly with the extension method provided in the intellisense for Dataview,in DataView sort result will come alphabetically only,
   However, to meet your requirement, I have created my own extention method for DataTable

   ```
   public static DataTable Sort(this DataTable dt, string ColumnName, string param)
   {
       DataTable dtCopy = new DataTable();
       List<DataRow> list = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
       list.Sort((x, y) => Convert.ToString(x[ColumnName]).ToLower().IndexOf(param).CompareTo(Convert.ToString(y[ColumnName]).ToLower().IndexOf(param)));
       dtCopy = list.CopyToDataTable();
       return dtCopy;
   }
   ```

   this will sort the Data with the filter parameter(in your case "na")

   ```
   //ColumnName is EmployeeName In your Case and filter text is txtSearchValue.Text   
   DataTable dt2 = table.Sort("ColumnName", txtSearchValue.Text); 
   DataView dv = dt2.DefaultView;
   ```
2. Your requirement can b met by another method,and in very small code by using Lambda Expression,

   ```
   DataTable dt3 = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(s => Convert.ToString(s["ColumnName"]).IndexOf(txtSearchValue.Text)).CopyToDataTable();
   DataView dv = dt3.DefaultView;
   ```